# Can a Cocoa app launch the Main() of a SEPARATE Carbon bundle in the same App package?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, bundle, macos-carbon

Imagine, if you will, a Mac OS X .app package containing two programs: one with a Cocoa main() that returns NSApplicationMain(), and a separate bundle that has a Carbon executable with its own main().

The Cocoa app is for registration/activation.  We do not want to separate them into two apps.  I want to start execution on the Carbon main() from INSIDE the Cocoa main().  Assuming all code is properly signed, are multiple bundles with "main()" permitted in the same app package, and how does one launch a Carbon main() from inside the Cocoa code?

Comment: Couldn't you just launch the second bundle using `openURL:` or `launchAppWithBundleIdentifier` or similar? Why do you need to run it from *inside* the app?

Comment: @jtbandes -- trust me, the details are long and involved, but the Cocoa code must run before the Carbon code.  Only if the Cocoa code has set up what the Carbon app needs, can the Carbon app run properly.  The Cocoa code needs to invoke the launch of the Carbon code.  Won't launchAppWithBundleIdentifier() be looking for the app package with the Bundle Identifier at myApp.app/Contents/info.plist?

Comment: Well, it sounds like your Carbon app has a separate bundle, so it could(should?) have a different bundle ID.

Comment: And I've never tried this, but I imagine `dyld` might be a way to load and execute the other bundle's code, if you must do it that way.

Comment: Lots of applications contain helper applications which they launch. iTunes is an obvious example. Look inside it; you'll find the iTunesHelper application. So I have to wonder what you think the problem is. Did you _try_ this? When you did, what happened?

Comment: @matt -- You weren't kidding -- iTunes is an excellent example.  My concern was launching a Carbon app from within the main() of the Cocoa app.  I'll try launchApplicationAtURL(), because I need to be sure I'm only launching the Carbon app from WITHIN the same app package.  Wouldn't using the CFBundleIdentifier with launchAppWithBundleIdentifier() be unpredictable if multiple copies of the same app were present (like older versions the user didn't uninstall)?

Comment: Yes, launchApplicationAtURL makes a lot of sense for this use case. I thought something like that existed but couldn't find the name of it when I wrote my first comment.

Comment: Also note that if you really want to do ObjC calls from the Cocoa main() before NSApplicationMain() runs, you should create (and then drain) an autorelease pool

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really answering this question myself:  the legendary Eric Schlegel at Apple DTS communicated some additional considerations, so I'm posting them here for others that may wish to follow in my unusual footsteps:

> I don’t think this will work in the way that you want it to do. Once
>   the Cocoa app has run its event loop and registered with the window
>   server, that process will be marked as a Cocoa app. You’ll probably
>   run into weird behavior if you then try to run an entirely Carbon
>   event loop and window hierarchy, since everything in the OS will be
>   thinking you’ve got a Cocoa app even though you really are just using
>   Carbon.
>
> In this case, you’re better off just launching your main Carbon app as
>   a separate process.
>
> Having said that, I don’t think there’s actually any particular
>   difficulty in loading your separate Carbon bundle and running it.
>   You’d just use NSBundle or CFBundle to load the bundle by URL, get a
>   function pointer from the bundle for the exported main() function, and
>   call it. Away you go.

HOWEVER -- Neither CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(myBundle, CFSTR("_main")) nor CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(myBundle, CFSTR("main")) work on the Carbon .app Mach-o binary -- it returns this error:

```
Attempt to load executable of a type that cannot be dynamically loaded for CFBundle
```